# How can I use a template for display mode with the Mailchimp module when I add an article?

Tags: emails

How can I add a specific template for a display mode with the Mailchimp module?

I created a new display mode (*mailchimp*); then I selected it in /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display. I tried to add a template (*node--article--mailchimp.html.twig*) in my front template as usual, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you confirm that template name was suggested in Twig debug output?